# How do I repeat the serial numbers from 000 to 999 in php and save it in a txt file

Tags: php

How do I repeat the serial numbers from 000 to 999 in php and save it in a txt file

For example, I have this code

```
    <?php    
$bb=fopen('log.txt','w');
for ($i=0;$i<=999;$i++) 
    echo str_pad($i,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT),"\n","<br/>";
fwrite($bb,"$i");
fclose($bb);
?>
```

I want to make it like this

```
    <?php    
$bb=fopen('log.txt','w');
for ($i=0;$i<=999;$i++) 
    $mm = str_pad($i,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT),"\n","<br/>";
fwrite($bb,"$mm");
fclose($bb);
?>
```

Comment: Use a `.` when concatenating the parts of `$mm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sames be good, but have some issue.
First you should initialize `$mm` by empty string, then in loop you can use `.` to concatenating all numbers.

The other problem is `,"\n","<br/>"`: you changes this line from `echo`, and caused this issue, simply replace `,` by '.' to solve this one.

```
$bb = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
$mm = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 999; $i++)
{
    $mm .= str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
}
fwrite($bb, "$mm");
fclose($bb);
```